# Create .listing file using use Net::SFTP::Foreign

Tags: perl, sftp, perl-module

The below program is downloading files from an SFTP server, but I want to create a .listing file in the `localdirectory` from `sftpdirectory`'s file list. How do I create this using Net::SFTP::Foreign?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;

my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(
    'username@hostname',
    password => 'password',
    more     => ['-v']
);

$sftp->get('sftpdirectory/data.zip', 'localdirectory')
  or die "unable to retrieve copy: ".$sftp->error;

$sftp->disconnect;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution that retrieves all the remote entries into an array and them dumps it:

```
# untested!
my $ls = $sftp->ls('sftpdirectory')
    or die "ls failed: " . $sftp->error;
open my $fh, '>', 'localdirectory/listing' or die "unable to create file: $!";
print $fh $_->{longname}, "\n" for @$ls;
close $fh;
```

Memory efficient solution that writes the remote entries to the `.listing` file as they are retrieved from the remote host:

```
open my $fh, '>', 'localdirectory/.listing' or die "unable to create file: $!";

my $wanted = sub {
    print $fh $_[1]{longname}, "\n";
    0;
}

unless ($sftp->ls('sftpdirectory', wanted => $wanted)) {
    close $fh;
    unlink 'localdirectory/.listing';
    die "ls failed: ". $sftp->error;
}
close $fh;
```